# Not able to mount rootfs on zedboard

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel, u-boot

I am having issues in loading my root fs and after inspecting the Kernel Log it says some thing like

"INITRD: 0x1f8ca000+0x0028ac63 is not a memory region - disabling initrd"

What does this mean?

Background

I am running linux on one core of an ARM Cortex A9 and trying to run another baremetal application on another core. I have changed the device tree to reflect this and i am reserving part of the SDRAM for Linux and part for the bare-metal application. I am using Uboot. Is this something to do with the uboot?

Cheers,
S

Comment: Can you post your Uboot configuration and Linux kernel version?  That message comes from arch/arm/mm/init.c.  memblock_is_region_memory() is failing.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing me towards that file. It was indeed because my kernel was trying to load the Ramdisk outside the address range which i had allocated for my linux in the device tree ( which is done by the uboot) fixed it by setting the variable initrd_high

Answer (score 1):

As you are NOT dedicating the entire RAM to the Linux kernel on the main core, you will need to ensure that the intrd load address specified in the bootargs is accesible from the main core.

Next, this info is usually passed to the Linux kernel in bootargs passed from u-boot as

```
initrd=<initrd-start-addr>,<initrd-size>
```

Modify it according to your custom memory-map

Finally in u-boot, load the initrd at the new proper address you just specified and boot the Linux kernel.

Comment: Hi, I fixed it without doing this. But the reason you mentioned was correct. The problem was my Ramdisk was getting loaded outside the RAM memory which linux could see. So i just set the env variable initrd_high to specify the maximum address linux can use.

Comment: The memory map that restricts the complete RAM from being used, defined in the bootargs of u-boot (or the DTS, in your case) is for the Linux kernel. As you are using u-boot to load the `initrd` image into RAM, you need to notify u-boot about the RAM restriction as well. As you mentioned, you achieved this using `initrd_high` in u-bbot which is indeed used by u-boot to decide where to load the image. :-)

Comment: Oh yea i typed a bigger comment asking a question but later realized what you just mentioned :D . thanks.